# remove first spacing of lines nodejs

Tags: node.js

hello i have a txt problem but when i deleted the line i have a space i want to remove the line spacing

my txt is like this

I tried to erase it in regex in several ways none works
I tried with his
[\ r \ n] +. and its ^ (?: [\ t] * (?: \ r? \ n | \ r)) +

and its \ s + (?! [^,])

is there the possibility of simulating a key down arrow and a backspace or if you have a better solution I am a taker
->first line
abc
abc

```
 fs = require('fs');
    data = fs.readFileSync('list.txt', 'UTF-8');
    lines = data.split('\r\n');
      for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
        var newValue = data.replace(lines[i] , '');
        
        fs.writeFileSync('list.txt' , newValue   );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `newValue` each time in the for loop, meaning that your output is just going to be the last line with the given code.

Perhaps something a little more simple would work for you, if you're just trying to replace the newlines.

```
 fs = require('fs');
 data = fs.readFileSync('list.txt', 'UTF-8');
 lines = data.split('\r\n').join('');
 fs.writeFileSync('list.txt' , lines);
```

Or even more simply put:

```
 fs = require('fs');
 data = fs.readFileSync('list.txt', 'UTF-8');
 // note the "g" for "global" in the RegExp
 fs.writeFileSync('list.txt' , data.replace(/\r\n/g,""));
```

Comment: this work but i want removing blank line data.replace(/\r\n/g,"")) this or this data.replace(lines[i] , ''); replace lines but i got the first line but i got line blank and i have try many thing for removing and nothing if you have an idea about this if i can simulate keypress down arrow and backspace to remove the first blank line or a trick like regex thanks you in avance for your help

Comment: `"\r\n\r\ntest\r\n".replace(/\r\n/g,"")` replaces even if there is a first blank line. So perhaps your first blank line is just `\r` or `\n` ? What number do you get if you do `data.charCodeAt(0)`? and `(1)` ? (e.g. `"A".charCodeAt(0)` returns `65` )

Comment: thanks you i have solved my problem by this way var newValue = data.replace(lines[i] , '');
   fs.writeFileSync('list.txt' , newValue   );
   fs.writeFileSync('list.txt' ,  data.replace(/^(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+/g ,"") );

Comment: excuse me sir i have a other question i have set up process on handled error on my script  but on handled error if script die it run again but i want to set up one thing if the script got like 10 error the processs exit the script i have try like this but i don't know if it's good  process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.error('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
   run();
});
if(process.on('unhandledRejection') == 10 {
 process.exit();
}

Comment: The `unhandledRejection` event handler should really be used as a *final* process exit. Use `try` and `catch` in your program instead.

Comment: thank you for your precious help its helped me a lot and for the rejection handler here I need it to be realized in this way that when it realizes 10 error it quits the procedure I did something but I do not know if it is is correct i have not yet come across the error case to see it i could see it that in the practical case of my script is that you can take a look at this and tell me if this is correct

Comment: process.on ('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.error ('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
   run ();
});
if (process.on ('unhandledRejection', == 10, (reason, p) => {
  process.exit ();
}

Comment: hello sorry for bothoring you can you help me with this query ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361911/i-would-like-to-create-an-unhandledrejection-if-it-returns-several-errors-afterw