# my xhr status return allways 200 however in my condition if it does not take it into account

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with my xhr. The xhr status returns always 200. However, in my condition `if` it does not take it into account.

In the condition it goes directly to the `else` while the `xhr.status` returns the response 200. In the condition I put an `if` the response was 200 then it was using this :

```
console.log ('hello');
```

However, he sends this back to me

```
console.log ('salut');
```

My code :

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('node-http-xhr');
 

global.XMLHttpRequest = require('node-http-xhr');


var url = "https://www.google.com/";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
     console.log(xhr.status);
   }};


xhr.send();

if(xhr.status == 200){
  console.log('bonjour');
  }else{
    console.log('salut');
    
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the response of your request right after the line `xhr.send()`. The result is available in the `onreadystatechange` function. So, you need to move your condition into this function.

Change from :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
     console.log(xhr.status);
}};

xhr.send();

if(xhr.status == 200) {
  console.log('bonjour');
} else {
  console.log('salut');  
}
```

to :

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
     console.log(xhr.status);
   }

   // move the condition here
   if(xhr.status == 200) {
      console.log('bonjour');
   } else {
     console.log('salut');
   }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: this good but this launch 3 time again on the console. you know why

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, you can upvote or mark it as accepted :)

Comment: ahahaha really help full ;) if you want you can help me again with my other topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454605/click-on-checkbox-using-puppetter